# Using jqGrid with .NET MVC Json Data won't load -columns showing ok

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am having a tough time loading data from .NET MVC 4.0.01 and I have been doing extensive research on the JQgrid site and documentation but cannot seem to find the issue.

And in my Grid (I'm using jqGrid 4.9.2)

```js
$(function () {
    gridMs = $("#jqGridMSats").jqGrid({
        url: "Status/GetMissingItems",
        //contentType: "application/json",
        datatype: "json",
        loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(status + " " + error); },
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["SattId", "SattUId", "SattScannedId", "SattName",
         "SattAntenna", "SattCount", "SattFirstDiscovered", "SattLastSeen", "ZoneUId", 
         "ContainerId", "SattPlanUId", "Details"],

        colModel: [{ name: "SattId", index: "SattId", hidden: false, width: 100 },
                   { name: "SattUId", index: "SattUId", align: 'left', hidden: true, search: false, sortable: true, width: 75 },
                   { name: "SattScannedId", index: "SattScannedId", align: 'left', search: false, sortable: true, width: 75 },
                   { name: "SattName", index: "SattName", align: 'center', hidden: false, width: 30 },
                   { name: "SattAntenna", index: "SattAntenna", align: 'center', hidden: false, width: 30 },
                   { name: "SattCount", index: "SattCount", align: 'center', hidden: false, width: 30 },
                   { name: "SattFirstDiscovered", index: "SattFirstDiscovered", align: 'center', hidden: true, formatter: 'date',
                       formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }, search: true, sortable: true, width: 80,
                       searchoptions: {
                           dataInit: function (element) {
                               $(element).daterangepicker({
                                   id: 'Discovered',
                                   dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                                   minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1),
                                   maxDate: new Date(2025, 0, 1),
                                   showOn: 'focus',
                                   onSelect: function () {
                                       //var startDate = $(el).val().start;
                                       //var endDate = $(el).val().end;
                                       //alert("Start: " + startDate + " End: " + endDate);
                                   }
                               });
                           },
                           // show search options
                           sopt: ["ge", "le", "eq"] // ge = greater or equal to, le = less or equal to, eq = equal to
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       name: "SattLastSeen", index: "SattLastSeen", align: 'center', stype: 'text', formatter: 'date',
                        formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }, search: true, sortable: true, width: 90,
                       searchoptions: {
                           // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                           // use it to place a third party control to customize the toolbar
                           dataInit: function (el) {
                               $(el).daterangepicker({
                                   id: 'drpLS',
                                   dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                                   minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1),
                                   maxDate: new Date(2025, 0, 1),
                                   showOn: 'focus',
                                   onClose: function () {
                                       var misDate = $(el).val();
                                       var dtArray = misDate.split('-');
                                       var startdate = dtArray[0].trim();
                                       var endDate = dtArray[1].trim();

                                   }
                               });
                           },
                           // show search options
                           sopt: ["ge", "le", "eq"] // ge = greater or equal to, le = less or equal to, eq = equal to
                       }
                   },
                   { name: "ZoneUId", index: "ZoneUId", align: 'center', sortable: true, width: 60 },
                   { name: "ContainerId", index: "ContainerId", align: 'center', hidden: false, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                   { name: "SattPlanUId", index: "SattPlanUId", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                   { name: "Details", index: "Details", align: 'center', width: 30, hidden: true, search: false, formatter: function (cellvalue) {
                           return "<img src='../../Content/finder.png' alt='Locate sat' />";
                       }
                   }
        ],
        width: 770,
        height: 'auto',
        loadonce: true,
        //rowNum: 11,
        pager: "#jqGridPagerMSatts",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Missing",
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        footerrow: true,
        loadComplete: function () { alert("loaded"); },

        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            repeatitems: false,
            page: function (obj) { return 1; }, // page as 1
            total: function (obj) { return 1; }, // total  as 1
            records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
        },

        onCellSelect: function (rowid, index) {
            var cm = gridMs.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
            if (cm[index].name == 'Details' && satValue.indexOf("----") == -1) {
                alert('test');
            }
        },

    });

    gridMs.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, searchOperators: true });
    gridMs.navGrid('#jqGridPagerMSatts', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });

});
```

My client side references:

```html
    <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqGridM/css/ui.jqgrid.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqGridM/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js") %>" ></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqGridM/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js") %>" ></script>
```

My columns load and the total records show. But cannot get the data to show. I've tried changing the controller to return a JavascriptSerializer format but still the same. I also removed the dates column thinking maybe it's a format issue but still the same results- no data shown. I get no errors at all when checking (Response) from Chrome. I have another grid in the same page which I can push dynamic data to just fine however loading the data from MVC Action is the problem. Is there something I am missing in my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how the FULL page renders in Chrome. If I invoke the missingTagGrid function first that Grid shows the data fine. Then if I select the resetGrid afterwards it loads fine too. If I select the resetGrid function first however the other grid won't load but it will show the colums and total pages....no errors in Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1">
        <title></title>
        <link href="/Content/Css/Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/Css/History.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/Css/AnyTime.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/Inventory/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/Inventory/ui.daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Scripts/jqGridM/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Content/Css/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/spectrum.js"></script>  
        <link type="text/css" href="/Content/telerik.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link type="text/css" href="/Content/telerik.vista.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>                   
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var inventoryData = [];
            var missingData = [];
            var mydata;
            var rowMissing = 0;
            var rowTotals;
            var rowMissingMis = 0;
            var rowtotalsMis;
            var isMissing = false;
            var mydata = [];
            var newCompArray = [];
            var machineName = 'bcd44e4c';
            var registeredGrp = 'ACME Lgstks';
        </script>

    <form method="post" action="Status" id="form1"><div>
        <div id="timeDiv"></div>
        <div id="stsGrid" style="float: left;">
            <div id="tagStatus" style="width: 560px;">
            <div id="invGrid">    
            <table id="jqGrid"></table>
            <div id="jqGridPager"></div></div>
            <div id="misGrid">
             <table id="jqGridMTags"></table>
           <div id="jqGridPagerMTags"></div>
           </div>
          </div>    
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>       
</form>
    <div id="removeChildModal" class="jqmWindow section">
    </div>    
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#misGrid').hide();
       </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resetGrid() {
            $('#misGrid').hide();
            $('#invGrid').show();
            var gridData;
            var rowIds;
            var messenger = $.connection.messenger;

            $("#jqGridMTags").hide();
            gridInv = null;
            //<![CDATA[
            $(function () {
                'use strict';

                var mydata = [], //Need this for SignalR

                    gridInv = $("#jqGrid");
                gridInv.jqGrid({
                    datatype: "jsonstring",
                    datastr: inventoryData,
                    colNames: ["Antenna", "Content", "Count", "Direction", "Discovered", "Duration", "EPC", "Freq","LastSeen", "Name", "Pack", "RSSI", "Size", "Speed", "Title", "Type", "Zone", "Find"],
                    colModel: [{name: "Antenna", index: "Antenna", key: true, hidden: true, width: 100, cellattr: function (rowId) {if (rowId < 5) { return 'colspan=8'; }}
                    },
                        { name: "Content", index: "Content", align: 'left', search: false, sortable: true, width: 75 },
                        { name: "Count", index: "Count", align: 'center', search: false, sortable: true, width: 40 },
                        { name: "Direction", index: "Direction", align: 'center', hidden: true, width: 30 },
                        { name: "Discovered", index: "Discovered", align: 'center', stype: 'text', search: true, sortable: true, width: 80,
                            searchoptions: {
                                // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                                // use it to place a third party control to customize the toolbar
                                dataInit: function (element) {$(element).daterangepicker({id: 'Discovered',dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1),maxDate: new Date(2025, 0, 1),
                                        showOn: 'focus'
                                    });
                                },
                                // show search options
                                sopt: ["ge", "le", "eq"] // ge = greater or equal to, le = less or equal to, eq = equal to
                            }
                        },
                        { name: "Duration", index: "Duration", align: 'center', hidden: true, width: 60 },
                        { name: "EPC", index: "EPC", align: 'center', sortable: true, width: 140 },
                        { name: "Freq", index: "Freq", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 50 },
                        {
                            name: "LastSeen", index: "LastSeen", align: 'center', stype: 'text', search: true, sortable: true, width: 80,
                            searchoptions: {
                                dataInit: function (element) {$(element).daterangepicker({id: 'LastSeen',dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1),maxDate: new Date(2025, 0, 1),showOn: 'focus'});},
                                // show search options
                                sopt: ["ge", "le", "eq"] // ge = greater or equal to, le = less or equal to, eq = equal to
                            }
                        },
                        { name: "Name", index: "Name", align: 'center', sortable: true, width: 50 },
                        { name: "Pack", index: "Pack", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                        { name: "RSSI", index: "RSSI", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 50 },
                        { name: "Size", index: "Size", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                        { name: "Speed", index: "Speed", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                        { name: "Title", index: "Title", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                        { name: "Type", index: "Type", align: 'center', width: 33, search: false, formatter: function (cellvalue) {
                                if (cellvalue == "----") return "----";
                                if (cellvalue == "None" || cellvalue === 'undefined' || cellvalue == '')
                                    return "<img src='../../Scripts/Tree/skin/0000.png' alt='Locate tag' />";
                                else
                                    return "<img src='../../Scripts/Tree/skin/" + cellvalue + ".png' alt='Locate tag' />";
                            }
                        },
                        { name: "Zone", index: "Zone", align: 'center', search: true, sortable: true, width: 50 },
                        { name: "Find", index: "Find", align: 'center', width: 25, search: false, formatter: function (cellvalue) {
                                if (cellvalue == "----") return "----";
                                else
                                    return "<img src='../../Content/finder.png' alt='Locate tag' />";
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    width: 770,
                    height: 428,
                    gridview: true,
                    rowattr: function (rd) {
                        if (rd.Find === "----") { // verify it's Zone parent
                            return { "class": "zoneHdr" };
                        }
                        else
                            return { "class": "selected-row" };

                    },
                    loadonce: true,
                    rowNum: 11,
                    pager: "#jqGridPager",
                    sortname: 'Antenna',
                    treeGrid: true,
                    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
                    treedatatype: "jsonstring",
                    ExpandColumn: 'Content',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "Inventory List",
                    footerrow: true,
                    grouping: false,

                    jsonReader: {
                        repeatitems: false,
                        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
                    },

                    onCellSelect: function (rowid, index) {
                        var tagValue = gridInv.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Title');
                        var zneValue = gridInv.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Zone');

                        var cm = gridInv.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                        if (cm[index].name == 'Find' && tagValue.indexOf("----") == -1) {
                            localStorage.setItem("tagStore", tagValue);
                            localStorage.setItem("zneStore", zneValue);
                        }
                        window.location = "/Package";
                    },
                });
                gridInv.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, searchOperators: true });
                gridInv.navGrid('#jqGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });
                gridInv.navButtonAdd('#jqGridPager', {
                    caption: "Click to show missing tags",
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-tag",
                    position: "last",
                    onClickButton: function () {
                        alert("Deleting Row");
                    }
                });
            });

            gridData = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData');
            for (var key in gridData[0]) {rowIds = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getCol', key, true);
                break;
            }
            if (typeof gridData != "undefined" && typeof rowIds != "undefined") {
                $.each(gridData, function (id) {var $row = $('#' + rowIds[id].id);
                    $row.show();});
            }

            rowTotals = ($('#jqGrid').getGridParam('records') - 4);
            rowMissing = 0;

            $('#jqGrid').jqGrid("footerData", "set", { Content: "<span style='color:red'>Total Missing:</span>", Count: "<span style='color:red'>" + rowMissing + "</span>", LastSeen: "Total Inventoried:", Name: rowTotals });
            $("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");

            messenger.server.broadCastReaderConfig(false, '');
            //
        }

        ///Missing Tags
        function missingTagGrid() {
            $('#misGrid').show();
            $('#invGrid').hide();
            var gridMs = null;
            //<![CDATA[
            $(function () {
                gridMs = $("#jqGridMTags").jqGrid({
                    url: "Status/GetMissingItems",
                    //contentType: "application/json",
                    datatype: "json",
                    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(status + " " + error); },
                    mtype: "GET",
                    colNames: ["TagId", "TagUId", "TagScannedId", "TagName", "TagAntenna", "TagCount", "TagFirstDiscovered", "TagLastSeen", "ZoneUId", "ContainerId", "FloorplanUId", "Details"],

                    colModel: [{ name: "TagId", index: "TagId", hidden: false, width: 100 },
                               { name: "TagUId", index: "TagUId", align: 'left', hidden: true, search: false, sortable: true, width: 75 },
                               { name: "TagScannedId", index: "TagScannedId", align: 'left', search: false, sortable: true, width: 75 },
                               { name: "TagName", index: "TagName", align: 'center', hidden: false, width: 30 },
                               { name: "TagAntenna", index: "TagAntenna", align: 'center', hidden: false, width: 30 },
                               { name: "TagCount", index: "TagCount", align: 'center', hidden: false, width: 30 },
                               {
                                   name: "TagFirstDiscovered", index: "TagFirstDiscovered", align: 'center', hidden: true, formatter: 'date',
                                   formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }, search: true, sortable: true, width: 80,
                                   searchoptions: { dataInit: function (element) {
                                           $(element).daterangepicker({
                                               id: 'Discovered',
                                               dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                                               minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1),
                                               maxDate: new Date(2025, 0, 1),
                                               showOn: 'focus',
                                               onSelect: function () {
                                               }
                                           });
                                       },
                                       sopt: ["ge", "le", "eq"] // ge = greater or equal to, le = less or equal to, eq = equal to
                                   }
                               },
                               { name: "TagLastSeen", index: "TagLastSeen", align: 'center', stype: 'text', formatter: 'date',
                                   formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }, search: true, sortable: true, width: 90,
                                   searchoptions: { dataInit: function (el) {
                                           $(el).daterangepicker({
                                               id: 'drpLS',
                                               dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                                               minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1),
                                               maxDate: new Date(2025, 0, 1),
                                               showOn: 'focus',
                                               onClose: function () {
                                                   var misDate = $(el).val();
                                                   var dtArray = misDate.split('-');
                                                   var startdate = dtArray[0].trim();
                                                   var endDate = dtArray[1].trim();
                                               }
                                           });
                                       },
                                       sopt: ["ge", "le", "eq"] // ge = greater or equal to, le = less or equal to, eq = equal to
                                   }
                               },
                               { name: "ZoneUId", index: "ZoneUId", align: 'center', sortable: true, width: 60 },
                               { name: "ContainerId", index: "ContainerId", align: 'center', hidden: false, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                               { name: "FloorplanUId", index: "FloorplanUId", align: 'center', hidden: true, sortable: true, width: 60 },
                               { name: "Details", index: "Details", align: 'center', width: 30, hidden: true, search: false, formatter: function (cellvalue) {
                                       return "<img src='../../Content/finder.png' alt='Locate tag' />";
                                   }
                               }
                    ],
                    width: 770,
                    height: 'auto',
                    loadonce: true,
                    pager: "#jqGridPagerMTags",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "Missing",
                    gridview: true,
                    autoencode: true,
                    footerrow: true,

                    jsonReader: {
                        root: "rows",
                        repeatitems: false,
                        page: function (obj) { return 1; }, // page as 1
                        total: function (obj) { return 1; }, // total  as 1
                        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
                    },

                    onCellSelect: function (rowid, index) {
                        var cm = gridMs.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                        if (cm[index].name == 'Details' && tagValue.indexOf("----") == -1) {
                            alert('Pop up to decribe missing tag in detail');
                        }
                    },

                });

                gridMs.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, searchOperators: true });
                gridMs.navGrid('#jqGridPagerMTags', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });


            });
        }

        <!-- other content -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/telerik.common.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/telerik.list.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/SignalR.StatusHub.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/trirand/jquery.jqDropDownList.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/trirand/jquery.jqDatePicker.min.js" ></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/trirand/jquery.jqAutoComplete.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqGridM/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" ></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqGridM/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqGridM/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/InventoryScripts/date.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/InventoryScripts/daterangepicker.jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you posted correct code and you inserted `<table id="jqGridMSats"></table><div id="jqGridPagerMSatts"></div>` on you page? I can't reproduce any problem with initial filling of the grid. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetMissingItems.htm) which uses your code. By the way you can reduce the JavaScript code and it will do the same.

Comment: I notice a few lines of references I don't have (yes I did post all code that is relevant) however, these references:

    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
        var wscreen=$(window).width()-20;
    </script>

    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>


Are they needed?

Comment: only the last one line which includes `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` (or `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`) is really required. I removed some unneeded lines from the demo. Can you provide *your demo* which have the problem?

Comment: Ok, sure, but let me check your demo again sir

Comment: Like would you like a live link to the actual site (is this what you mean by demo?)

Comment: One need to include jqGrid. I used the code from GitHub, but one can use in the same way the local downloaded code or the code from CDN, for example `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.9.2/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js` (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). Do you found the reason of the problem in *your code*? If not, then do you prepared the demo which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Ok I found the issue (though I'm still trying to figure out how to solve it). I have two grids in the page as mentioned above. One grid I push data to locally (dymaically) the other as you see posted gets data returned from MVC Controller action. The problem is a reference problem. I reference Jquery, JqGrid and few other third party and custom js files in the Master Page. If I move the JQuery 1.11.0 reference from the head tag (the JQgrid references are at the bottom of the page) the local data Grid works fine the other (mvc action)  shows no data. But if it's in the head it's the opposite.

Comment: Actually if I the move the JQgrid references in the head below the JQuery reference then I get reference errors in the browser "JqGrid" not a function. The local data grid loads on page load the mvc action grid is in a function called by button event. When I put both grids in a function from button click event they both loaded fine, but after hiding/showing one grid the mvc action grid would not reload spite using the trigger reload with the action call parameter.

Comment: You should just include **full** HTML and JavaScript code from the page. It seems that you organize the code in the wrong way. You can post the code where you place all JavaScript code on the `<head>` and only the `<table>`/`<div>` elements are in the `<body>` like I did in my demo.

Comment: Shown through the edit

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong order of included JavaScript data and you placed some HTML element on the wrong place. For example you placed in `<head>` of the page the following JavaScript files

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/spectrum.js"></script>
```

You have to include jQuery **before** `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` which depends from jQuery.

The next error: you included **two different version of the same file**. For example, You included `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` in the `<head>` and then placed `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js` in the `<body>`. It's wrong. In the same way it's wrong to include both non-minimized and minimized version of the same JavaScript library. See `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` included directly after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

You used `jquery-1.7.1.js` which is not an error, but I would strictly recommend you don't uses such retro version of jQuery. Instead of that you should use jQuery 1.11.3 or jQuery 2.1.4 if you don't need to support old web browsers IE6, IE7 and IE8.

I places `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` inside of `<body>`. It's wrong. All `<meta>` should be included directly after `<title>`. Don't forget to include

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

which is required to prevent using compatibility mode of IE.

Now about the code itself. It's difficult to read the code divided into many separate `<script></script>` parts. Moreover the code is either not full or some important functions will be not called or be called in the wrong order. You should first include jQuery, then include jqGrid and only after that you can use `jqGrid` method. Another problem: you **define** `resetGrid` and `missingTagGrid` function, but **never call there** (using `resetGrid();` or `missingTagGrid();`).

One more problem: The code

```js
$(function () {...});
```

is the short form of [document ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {...});
```

which wait till the document which includes the `<>` is loaded and then execute the function inside of it (`...` part). In the case the usage of document ready **inside of `<body>`** (inside of the document) is not a good idea. You should wither remove `$(function () {` part, but place the code **after** HTML parts which you used in the handler (after `<table id="jqGrid"></table>` for example) or better **to move the**  inside of `<head>`. Just examine once more [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetMissingItems.htm), which I posted before in the comment, under the aspect of the order included JavaScript files, the code, `<head>` and and `<body>`.

One more important aspect of JavaScript language: you should define variables of function *inside of another outer function* if it's possible. If you define variables directly on the top of the script like

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inventoryData = [];
    var missingData = [];
    var mydata;
    var rowMissing = 0;
    var rowTotals;
    var rowMissingMis = 0;
    var rowtotalsMis;
    var isMissing = false;
    var mydata = [];
    var newCompArray = [];
    var machineName = 'bcd44e4c';
    var registeredGrp = 'ACME Lgstks';
</script>
```

then you define **global** variables. It makes potential conflicts with another code which you included. For example if you would define `$ = 0` or `jQuery = null` in the way you will break the code of jQuery and and jQuery plugins. It's important to understand additionally that the above script not only define global variables, **it assign new properties to the global `window` object**. You can easy verify that `window` object have `rowMissing` property now and the value of the property is `0`. It would be much better to move the code inside of some function. For example the code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var rowMissing = 0, rowTotals;

    ...
    rowTotals = ($('#jqGrid').getGridParam('records') - 4);
    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        Content: "<span style='color:red'>Total Missing:</span>",
        Count: "<span style='color:red'>" + rowMissing + "</span>",
        LastSeen: "Total Inventoried:",
        Name: rowTotals
    });
    ...
});
</script>
```

is much better. It defined **local** variables `rowMissing` and `rowTotals` existing only inside the function and it uses the variables inside of the function. In the way one will have no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the biggest problem was Telerik's script register was embedding the older version of Jquery (jquery-1.7.1.js). I didn't notice it until you pointed it out. It's one of those things that Telerik does undercover so it was easy to miss. Great observation on the bad references, order and global vars, fixed those also. Thanks for all your help Oleg..you're truly awesome. Works like a charm now!